# Аварийно()опасный

Tags: орфография

Я написала слово "аварийноопасный" слитно, но Ворд мне его подчеркнул как ошибку и предложил написать раздельно: "Аварийно опасный".
Но понятие "аварийноопасный" достаточно распространенное, поэтому хочется написать его слитно. А как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно – раздельно. Вы, видимо, хотите писать слитно по аналогии с "пожароопасный". Но наречия "пожаро" не существует, а наречие "аварийно" – существует.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Букчиной Б.З.и Калуцкой Л.П. "Слитно или раздельно?" (1988) все 9 сложных прилагательных с АВАРИЙНО- пишутся через дефис: аварийно-низкий, аварийно-ремонтный и др. Думаю, что и аварийно-опасный нужно писать через дефис.

Answer (score 1):

Пока это слово не вошло в словари, правописание колеблется между раздельным и через дефис. На одном из форумов есть ответ справочной службы:

http://slovari21.ru/community/1253/

- Следует писать через дефис: аварийно-опасный. Во-первых, есть словообразовательный показатель, помогающий определиться с выбором написания. Речь идет о суффиксе -н- в первой части сложного слова. Во-вторых, если б это было наречие и прилагательное, то была возможна перестановка частей этого сочетания без потери смысла и без ущерба сочетаемости. В данном случае этого сделать нельзя, наречие аварийно самостоятельно используется только при глаголе в таких контекстах: аварийно сел самолет,аварийно приземлился самолет. В-третьих, дефисное написание подтверждается большим количеством слов с первой частью аварийно-: аварийно-спасательный, аварийно-восстановительный, аварийно-ремонтный.

Но я с этим не согласна, потому что аварийно-спасательный - это "аварийный и спасательный", а аварийно опасный - в значении "Опасный в каком-то отношении", как и в наречиях на -ски.

Вот, например, термин "аварийно химически опасные вещества"   пишется раздельно:        view_factors.php

В серьёзном учебнике, прошедшем редакцию Академии наук, тоже раздельно :
"В 1999 г. предприятия химической промышленности занимали
третье место в списке наиболее аварийно опасных производственных
объектов".   
http://www.chem.msu.su/rus/teaching/technorisk/menshikov/men1.pdf

В серьёзных московских газетах тоже раздельно. Так что выбирать Вам, как писать, - раздельно или через дефис, а вот слитно действительно, я согласна с Вордом, нежелательно, потому что там суффикс -Н-, нацеливающий на самостоятельность значения наречия.

Answer (score 0):

Русская орфография замечательна тем, что по форме  написания слова мы можем определить его значение.  Можно было бы написать «аварийно-опасный», НАЗНАЧИВ всем слова на «аварийно» ОДИНАКОВОЕ дефисное написание.  Но при таком подходе нам придется заучивать написание очень многих слов без понимания их смысла. А при семантико-грамматическом анализе  эта задача решается так.

1) «Аварийно» – это наречие или основа прилагательного ?

2) Делаем вывод, что это НАРЕЧИЕ со значением «с точки зрения аварийности». Тогда здесь возможно только  две формы: РАЗДЕЛЬНОЕ написание свободного сочетания наречия и прилагательного «аварийно опасный» или  СЛИТНОЕ написание термина «аварийноопасный» (термин получается путем сращения наречия и прилагательного).

3) Если «аварийно» – это ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ в составе сложного слова, то написание дефисное: аварийная опасная дорога – аварийно-опасная дорога.
Но дорога же не аварийная (в плохом состоянии), она просто потенциально опасная с точки зрения возможных аварий автомобилей. Дефисное написание ИСКАЖАЕТ смысл сложного слова.

4) Термина «аварийноопасный»  по аналогии с «пожароопасным»  в словарях нет, поэтому пока пользуемся раздельным написанием «аварийно опасный»  (до момента возможного  появления термина в словарях).

5) Пример: С 20 по 24 августа ― аварийно опасный период, когда повышается риск технических катастроф и экстремального поведения людей (астрологический прогноз).